# `set` option with variables

Tags: options, variables

I am trying to rewrite adding a string to option with variable. The original string is

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

The following is the working `let` way:

```
let MYVIMDIR='/home/loom/foo'
let &rtp .= ','.expand(MYVIMDIR).'/bundle/Vundle.vim'
```

I am interested how rewrite it with `set`. The following code (and some other variations) doesn't work

```
let MYVIMDIR='/home/loom/foo'
set rtp+=expand(MYVIMDIR).'/bundle/Vundle.vim'
```

What is the right way to use variables in expression with `set`?

Answer (score 16):

You could use `:exe`, but this is extremely cumbersome to use and you'll need to escape a few things.

I used to use my own path fixing function. It looked like:

```
exe 'set rtp+='.lh#path#fix(somevariable)
" with standard tools, may be it'd be (untested)
exe 'set rtp+='.escape(somevariable, ' \|,')
```

`let &rtp = expression` is really our friend.

But indeed, it doesn't play well with `+=`. That's why I've came up with `lh#path#munge()` that relies on another function `lh#list#add_if_new()`. Strictly speaking `set +=` is emulated by `lh#list#add_if_new()`. `munge()` keeps pathnames that do exist, or actually globbing patterns that match things.

```
" Function: lh#path#munge(pathlist, path) {{{3
function! lh#path#munge(pathlist, path) abort
  if type(a:pathlist) == type('str')
    let pathlist = split(a:pathlist, ',')
    return join(lh#path#munge(pathlist, a:path), ',')
  else
    " if filereadable(a:path) || isdirectory(a:path)
    if ! empty(glob(a:path)) " support '/**' for &tags
      call lh#list#push_if_new(a:pathlist, a:path)
    endif
    return a:pathlist
  endif
endfunction

" Function: lh#list#push_if_new(list, value) {{{3
function! lh#list#push_if_new(list, value) abort
  if index(a:list, a:value) < 0
    call add (a:list, a:value)
  endif
  return a:list
endfunction
```

They are defined and maintained in [lh-vim-lib](http://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib).

Comment: you also need to escape commas in the :set call

Answer (score 9):

You could use an environment variable defined within your current shell session.

```
let $myvimdir = '/home/abc/vimfiles'
```

That way you can use other variables to compose the path as well:

```
let $myvimdir = $HOME.'/vimfiles'
```

And set the runtime path:

```
set rtp+=$myvimdir/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

More information on environment variables within vim [:help expr-env](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-env)

Comment: Interesting. But when I try with `let $nts | set ts=$nts`, vim does not like it.

Comment: It's because environment variables are stored as strings and tabstop is expecting a number.